# Passing List or ArrayList of objects

Tags: java

```
List<Kevin> kevin = new ArrayList<Kevin>();
```

I have an List of Objects of Type Kevin, now does it make any difference on what i am passing to my method?.

```
void method1(List<Kevin>)

void method2(ArrayList<Kevin>)
```

It seems that both are working, is there any **difference** apart from that i would have access to `List interface related methods` on method1 and `array list related methods on method2.` I am just not sure whether we need to send `List` or `ArrayList` of objects.

Comment: List interface  methods will be available in both the cases

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They will both behave the same way. It's generally preferable to code to interfaces where possible, so *prefer* `List<Kevin>` (or even `Iterable<Kevin>` if you just need to iterate over the collection). If your method will only function properly if it's an `ArrayList<Kevin>`, that's fair enough... but otherwise, it's better not to restrict the caller to force them to pass in an `ArrayList`.

Comment: Thanks John. I am just confused over the Iterable<Kevin>, lets take i am passing my list of kevin objects to method1, can the reciever be either List or ArrayList or Iterable of type kevin?...

Comment: @Kevin: Any of them. But whether or not you can use `Iterable<Kevin>` will depend on what you want to do in the method. For example, you can't *add* to an `Iterable`.

Answer (score 2):

method1 will work fine for other implementations of List as well (e.g. LinkedList), while method2 is stricter and accept only one implementation. In general, try to make your method arguments as general as possible, for re-usability reasons.

Answer (score 2):

In most cases, it doesn't practically matter.  An `ArrayList` IS a `List` so any functionality you get from a `List` you will also get from an `ArrayList`.  And I should note, by the same principal, you may not actually get an `ArrayList` but rather some subclass that inherits from `ArrayList` (just like if you said `List`).

That said, it is typically considered best practice to require the most *general* type you need.  So, if you only need methods that `List` provides, then pass a `List` object, however, if there is something specific to `ArrayList` that you require then pass that.

Answer (score 1):

Passing an ArrayList would prevent you (or at least, make it more difficult) to change your mind and use another kind of `List` later, because `method2()` would rely on the list to be of type `ArrayList`, and not simply `List`.

Among the other List implementations that you could want to pass are `LinkedList`, `CopyOnWriteArrayList`, `Arrays.asList()`, `Collections.synchronizedList()`, or, often, `Collections.unmodifiableList()`.

The best practice is thus to program on interfaces, and pass a `List` (or even a `Collection` or `Iterable` if calling methods should not even assume it's a List).

For a private method inside the same class, it doesn't matter much. But if the method is part of a public API, then passing an ArrayList could really hurt you at some time.